# How to stop execCommand from pushing formatting through selected elements?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm using a contenteditable div to set up a basic editor. The content includes some elements that are "atomic" -- they're placeholders that aren't themselves editable. However, when the user selects such an element then chooses (for example) superscript, the formatting is being pushed through the span that represents the placeholder and into its content.

I've set up a minimal example below. Click "Click me" to apply superscript to the "Text" span, which should really be making the whole element (with its border) superscript. Instead, the borders stay normal and the superscript is pushed inside the span. Making the span "contenteditable=false", which I'd like to do since it's atomic, causes the reformatting to fail entirely.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("element");
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(element);
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);

  document.execCommand('superscript', false, false);
}
```

```css
#editor {
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  padding:10px;
}

#element {
  padding:3px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
}

#button {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='editor' contenteditable="true">
  Stuff <span id='element'>Text</span> something
</div>
<button id='button'>
  Click me
</button>
```

Is there a way to tell the browser that formatting should never be pushed inside of a particular element?